# Element-wise multiplication or Hadamard product

Tags: matrices, hadamard-product

$a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$ elements of matrix A and B (same dimensions).
I want to multiply the matrices element-wise so the resulting matrix $s$ have the same dimensions as A and B. Is this the correct way to express the mathematical operation?
And are they the same?

\begin{equation}
    s = \sum_{i}^n \sum_{j}^n w_{ij} a_{ij}
    \label{eq:observert}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    s = w_{ij} \odot a_{ij}
    \label{eq:hadamard}
\end{equation}

Comment: The first identity gives you a scalar.

Comment: Ah. That's right. my mistake.

Comment: The hadamard product of matrices $A$ and $B$ is represented as $A\odot B$.  The $i$'th row $j$'th column entry of the result would be the product of the $i$'th row $j$'th column entry of $A$ with the $i$'th row $j$'th column entry of $B$.

Comment: Why you have $w_{ij}$ apparently being the elements in $A$ and $a_{ij}$ being the elements of $B$ rather than $a_{ij}$ being the elements of $A$ and $b_{ij}$ the elements of $B$, I don't know.  Why you have the resulting matrix be written with lowercase $s$ instead of capital $S$ I don't know.  You would have $s_{ij}=w_{ij}\cdot a_{ij}$ where on the left this is in reference to the specific entry of the matrix and the product on the right is the usual product.  You ought to follow better naming conventions and keep better track of what is or isn't a matrix vs a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first identity gives you a scalar, not a matrix

The [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) of matrices $A$ and $B$ is usually denoted as $A\odot B$ and the element of $A\odot B$ is given by
$$
(A\odot B)_{ij}=(A)_{ij}(B)_{ij}
$$